# Do I read all the books in "The Sundering"?

Tags: novel, suggested-order

There are 6 books in "The Sundering" series, but only "the companions" is by R. A. Salvatore, and then there is a single book called "Night of the Hunter". Do I read the whole "Sundering" series and then the last book or just "The Companions"?

Comment: I can't find any mention of "Night of the Hunter" [here](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sundering_(series)) - how is it related to anything else in The Sundering?

Comment: @Izkata - It's the first book of the next series.

Answer (score 1):

### They can be read in any order without spoilering earlier or later novels in the series.

According to [Paul Kemp](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Paul_S._Kemp), author of "Forgotten Realms : The Resurrection", the final installation of "War of the Spider Queen" series and the "Erevis Cale" novels (as well as Webmaster of the official Forgotten Realms [website and wikia](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sundering_%28series%29)) the [Sundering](http://www.goodreads.com/series/92711-the-sundering) novels are intended to **stand alone** with **no continuous plotline, nor any substantial thematic connection between them**.

> During all this [e.g. the 'Era of Upheaval'], the six novels of The
>   Sundering series tell their stories — smaller stories, stories that
>   show the Sundering through the eyes of both ordinary folk and some of
>   Faerûn's iconic heroes. Each novel in The Sundering is self-contained.
>
> There are *some* connections between the novels — some Easter eggs, if
>   you will — but **each stands alone**. What they share is a common
>   background, with all of them occurring against the backdrop of the
>   Sundering.

For the record, one of the books you've mentioned ("[Night of the Hunter](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18050140-night-of-the-hunter)") isn't part of the Sundering series but is, in fact part of the larger Forgotten Realms series known as "[the Legend of Drizzt](http://www.goodreads.com/series/49134-the-legend-of-drizzt)". **This book should be read at the end of "The Sundering" Series of books** and forms the first book of a new short series known as the "Companions Codex" shortly to be followed by "[The Rise of the King](http://www.rasalvatore.com/article.aspx?siteNews=245)"